# PowerBI Datediff assistance needed

Tags: powerbi, datediff

Hello i have the following data and trying to calculate date difference in days between 2 different milestone completions

```
Identifer   Milestone Completion    Completion date
A   X   1/1/2018
A   Y   1/23/2018
B   X   1/8/2018
B   Y   1/15/2018
C   X   1/10/2019
C   Y   1/20/2019
```

My desired output is below

```
Identifer   Date Diff in Days
A   22
B   7
C   10
```

I need to figure out how to write a DAX expression to give me my desired output table. Do i need to calculate a new table. I am thinking of needing to use DATEDIFF and GROUPBY but not sure if that is the right approach and looking for suggestions